# Populate a nested list from a nested list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, nested

I have a list of Product (`IList<Product>`), with all data pre-populated.

Model: `Product`

```
public class Product
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentProductId { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Product> Children { get; set; } 

}
```

Property `Children` will be of type `IList<Product>`, means it is nested, it can again contain children up to `n` levels.

I have another model `FilterModel`.

Model: `FilterModel`

```
public class FilterModel
{
    //// This is same as that of Product Code
    public string Code { get; set; }

    //// This is a combination of Products Name, Id and some static strings
    public string FilterUrl { get; set; }

    public IList<FilterModel> Children
}
```

Which also has a same nested structure.

I planning to insert data into my second model (`FilterModel`) from the first (`Product`). Is this possible in a recursive way?

Comment: When you wrote "possible in a recursive way" you mean you want a new copy of every Child-Product? Or using the same reference is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
FilterModel Transfer(Product product)
{
    var fm = new FilterModel();
    fm.Code = product.Code;
    fm.Children = new List<FilterModel>();

    foreach (var p in product.Children)
    {
        fm.Children.Add(Transfer(p));
    }

    return fm;
}
```